# RANSAC line fitting (3d) by line segments (3d)

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

> I am having many 3d line segments. some of them are nearly parallel
>   and some are oriented in to different direction. I want to avoid
>   outliers and to get the best line 3d to represent the given 3d line
>   segments.

I am bit confused how RANSAC method apply for this case...

should i find a random line first or should i consider this as a given 3d point problem.?

can anyone post me the stucture to be followed when implenting this. thanks